# Как работает WebSecurityConfig, не открывается страница /login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, mustache

столкнулся с проблемой и не знаю как ее решить, делаю небольшое web приложение на spring boot и не понимаю как сделать страницу логина.
Вот мой класс WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }
}
```

А вот моя страница login

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example </title>
</head>
<body>
Login page
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf.token}}" />
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Я использую для создания шаблонов spring-boot-starter-mustache
И вот результат моей работы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть страница логина почему-то не открывается.

Answer (score 0):

вообщем нашел ошибку, она была в контролере, на который я и подумать не мог, к аннотации @GetMapping надо было добавить параметр ("/")